# How does WebPack Serve Pages/Chunks in Code Splitting?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How does WebPack serve different chunks when your user is on your website?

Because we have one `GET` request to server at the beginning - which would serve all of our `main.js`.

So then we go to a different page... We're not doing another `GET` request, but the server is able to serve this information?

Comment: It is getting from browser cache then, if you cannot see any request in network tab of browser. checkout this article - https://medium.com/prod-io/code-splitting-in-react-using-webpack-1aa1014da216

Comment: I'm actually not sure. Maybe there are more GET requests... I havent actually done it yet

Comment: okay, For every chunk web-pack creates there will be GET request. these linking of chunking is taken care internally by webpack itself.